# Como detectar mouse click fuera de la aplicacion en Qt

Tags: qt

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Qt, necesito detectar cuando se hace click fuera de la aplicación para ir alternando hide()-show() con cada click

Solucionado: por medio del evento void changeEvent(QEvent * e); donde podemos capturar la pérdida de foco de la ventana actual, sabemos cuando hemos echo click fuera de nuestra apliación.

MainWindow.h

```
    void changeEvent(QEvent * e);
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
     void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent * e){
    if(e->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange && this->isActiveWindow()){
       qDebug("focus in");
    } else {
       qDebug("focus out");
    }
```

}

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Podrías compartir con nosotros qué has intentado hasta ahora? Puedes leer la sección [ask] para tener más claro cómo formular una pregunta de calidad. Aportar un [mcve] ayudará a otros usuarios para dar mejores respuestas. Bienvenido a [es.so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes controlar la posicion del mouse para saber cuando pierdes el foco de la ventana y asi controlar cuando hagas click fuera:

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
{
        qDebug("focus lost");
        QPoint p=QCursor::pos();
        qDebug() << "mouse position=" << p;
        if ((p.x() >= 100 && p.x() <= 300) && (p.y() >= 100 && p.x() <= 700))
       {
    qDebug("hiding window");
    hide();
       }
}
_____________________________
```

EDITO:
Debes crear un metodo que escuche eventos del raton o manejar un QEventFilter, los eventos a manejar serian algo asi:

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
{
        qDebug("focus lost");
        return true;
}
else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
{
    QPoint pos = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->pos();
        qDebug() << "global=" << dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->globalPos();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: gracias por responder, cual sería el método que accedería al estar fuera el focus para implementar este código?

Comment: Tendrais que crear posiblemente un eventFilter o un metodo que escuche eventos del raton, investiga por ese lado, aunque creo que es el buen camino; te añado en la respuesta los QEvent a escuchar.

Si la respuesta te ha ayudado no dudes en marcarlo